# Php, fill hours missing in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array composed by starting hour and finish hour. Like:

```
8:00 --> 9:00
9:00 --> 10:00
12:00 --> 12:30
```

What i need is to fill the missings hours:

```
8:00 --> 9:00
9:00 --> 10:00
**10:00 --> 12:00**
12:00 --> 12:30
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. You need to do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_, post your attempt (with proper example data in the correct format), explain where you're stuck, the expected result and what currently happens. We're here to help you with concrete issues with your current code, not to write it all for you (which a proper answer here would require us to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the hours, and check that the las number of a loop is the same as the first number of the next loop, if not, add the interval:

```
<?php

# I have an array composed by starting hour and finish hour. Like:
$time_array = [
    '8:00' => '9:00',
    '9:00' => '10:00',
    // 10:00 => 12:00
    '12:00' => '12:30'
];

$last_time = '';
$new_time = [];
foreach ($time_array as $start => $end) {
    if ($last_time && $last_time != $start) {
        $new_time[$last_time] = $start;
    }
    $last_time = $end;
    $new_time[$start] = $end;
}
print_r($new_time);
```